# How do I download this video from Google Video?

Tags: download, streaming, flv, google-video

I have tried Orbit Downloader, but it can't seem to get it.

I know Google Video have updated their methods so it's harder now.

http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=3332918255822393647#

I've read of vixy being good, that links to a program called freecorder, but i've read of somebody installing it uninstalling it and being left with a toolbar. so I don't know whether freecorder would work or not but i'm not trying it yet.

If anybody can try downloading that 3min video and succeeds, then we're up to date! And i'd like to know the method. Any solution should describe the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [**DownloadHelper for Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/).

> Just surf the Web as you are used to, when DownloadHelper detects it can do something for you, the icon gets animated and a menu allows you to download files by simply clicking an item
>
> For instance, if you go to a YouTube page, you'll be able to download the video directly on your file system. It also works with MySpace, **Google videos**, DailyMotion, Porkolt, iFilm, DreamHost and others.

(emphasis in blockquote mine).  Free and works well!

I tried the particular video you linked to, and I can download it with the addon I mentioned above.

Comment: I've installed the extension. What do I click? I see the icon for it that looks like a molecule, in the toolbar and in the tools menu

Comment: @barlop: the "molecule" appears in color and starts turning/rotating when there is downloadable content on a webpage.  When you want to download something and the icon is turning, just click the little arrow to the right of the turning icon and a menu appears...

Comment: look still nulled out with that video  http://img195.imageshack.us/f/ffviid.jpg/

Comment: @barlop: don't wait too long into the video or switch tabs while the video is loading/playing because then it nulls out for me too...otherwise, it looks like it might be a problem with the addon or your browser... :(

Comment: got further this time, got the animated icon, got it listed in downloads, it just says "starting..." but no progress at all downloading. Ah, now just look again, and a pop up comes up that says all downloads complete.. and it's done.  I can view it. I will look further into it to see how I can see it progressing, doing that will be useful for bigger videos